# imagecreatefromjpeg not working properly

Tags: php, image, gd

I've been trying to resize an image using php but I'm having issues getting the imagecreatefromjpeg function to work. When I try to display an image, a whole bunch of characters appear on the screen, not the image. I don't see any errors either.

So, initially I tried to resize an image using this function. A bunch of random characters were displayed so I figured I'd simplify it for debugging.

```
function chgSize($image, $width, $height){
    $name = $image["name"]; //this is displaying the file name correctly
    $temp = $image["tmp_name"];
    $imageContents = imagecreatefromjpeg($temp);
    $blankImage = imagecreatetruecolor(100,100);

    if(imagecopyresampled($blankImage, $imageContents, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, $width, $height)){ 
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($blankImage, $name); //name the image and output it

        //$this->saveImage($formattedImage); //save the image, commented out for testing purposes
    }
}
```

**edit** - I got it to work. I didn't realize the second parameter in imagejpeg was the path, not just the image's name. On PHP's website parameter 2 was shown as a name in each instance, so I assumed that's all it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't output a content-type header to indicate to the browser that you're sending over JPEG image data. Add a

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

immediately before your imagejpeg() call.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the image to resize, however, I'm having difficulty setting the name now. Nothing happens when I try to echo the name. Just to verify this, I also tried to send it to my database and when submitted the name is blank. Thanks for your help.

Comment: imagejpeg returns true/false. it doesn't return an array. you really need to start reading the docs: http://php.net/imagejpeg

Comment: I used example #2 from the link you mentioned. All I'm trying to do is name the image and then echo it to check if the name is set properly. I meant to comment out the header(...) to reflect what I'm doing. In that example it says "Save the image as 'simpletext.jpg'" which is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: And yet again you fail to read the docs. imagecreatetruecolor returns a GD image handle, NOT AN ARRAY.

Comment: Marc, I got it to work. I did read the documentation, I just misinterpreted it. Example #2 shows imagejpeg's parameter 2 as just the name with no directory listed, so I didn't realize it is supposed to be the image's path, not just it's name.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the correct header?

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

You should also make sure you don't output any text before this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are printing out the raw data of a jpeg.  I'm not sure what your intended application is but you should either:

- Save the contents of $imgContents to a file on the server which can be served via an HTML image tag
- Output the proper HTTP headers to instruct the browser that the file it's receiving is actually a JPG, not HTML markup or text: `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my post? I updated it. I'm still having trouble getting it to name the picture.